# Проверка на EMPTY

Tags: php

Никогда не понимал принципа. Помогите пожалуйста.
Нужно проверить 3 поля на empty и соответственно выводить то, которое заполнено.

```
$town = town; //обязательное не может быть пустым
$info = info;
$name = name;
если пустые info и name, то выводить town
если пустой info, то выводить town и name
если пустой name, то выводить town и info
если все заполнены, то выводить town, name и info.
```

Через elseif не получается, я так понимаю нужно case заюзать.

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
if(empty($town)){
    die("Вы забыли указать город");
}else if(empty($info) && empty($name)){
    echo $town;
}else if(empty($info)){
    echo $town." и ".$name;
}else if(empty($name)){
    echo $town." и ".$info;
}else{
    echo $town." и ".$name." и ".$info;
}
```

Comment: ништяк. благодарствую. почему то не получалось у меня, хотя делал также.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так если поля постом передаются

```
 if(isset($_POST))
 {
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) {
        echo 'Поле: '.$key.', значение: '.$val;
    }
 }
```

Comment: foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)
{
    if(!empty($_POST['$key']))echo 'Поле: '.$key.', значение: '.$val;
}